# Undo last action in Canvas Html

Tags: html, canvas, restore, undo

I have a canvas which has two circular arcs one into another. I want a line to appear as I move my cursor between the Arcs([Inspiration](https://napchart.com/app)). I was able to draw the lines but I couldn't delete the previously drawn lines. I couldn't find anything to restore the previous drawn stage (Don't confuse this with context.restore() as it only gets to the point for you to then draw above it)

[My Code](http://oneclickpaste.com/5382/)
What I am currently doing is creating the whole canvas repeatedly for each mouseMove which is very inefficient and make further improvements complex. Any Help?

Comment: Redrawing the whole canvas (or at least the part of the canvas that has changed) is the correct way to use the html5 canvas element. It doesn't store previous states. You could draw the things that don't change to an invisible canvas and then draw the contents of that canvas to your main canvas before drawing the elements that change.

Comment: Can I do this in SVG?

Comment: yes, svg can do that